# inserting table data into data base have same names

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table with six rows and i have assigned same names to the  values to each row , how can i save the six row values into to the database using php in codeigniter

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="compscheme" id="compscheme" class="form-control m-b-10">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="compbrands" id="compbrands" class="form-control m-b-10">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" class="form-control m-b-10">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="cmpyscheme" id="cmpyscheme" class="form-control m-b-10">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="compscheme" id="compscheme" class="form-control m-b-10">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="compbrands" id="compbrands" class="form-control m-b-10">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" class="form-control m-b-10">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="cmpyscheme" id="cmpyscheme" class="form-control m-b-10">
    </td>
```

in this way i have six rows. should i use multiple array tag or any other way for inserting

Comment: you should use array like- companyname[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use array input name like- companyname[] -

```
<!--
<td>
    <input type="text" name="compscheme[]" id="compscheme" class="form-control m-b-10">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="compbrands[]" id="compbrands" class="form-control m-b-10">
</td>
.......
.......
.......
-->

<?php 

if(($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD')=='POST')){

    for ($i=0; $i <count($_POST['cmpyscheme']); $i++) { 

        $data=array(
                    'table_column_name'=>$_POST['cmpyscheme'][$i],
                );

        // for 6 rows 
        if($i==5){
            echo $_POST['cmpyscheme'][$i];
        }   
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get directly value of six row.

```
$cmpyscheme=$_POST['cmpyscheme'][5];
$compbrands=$_POST['compbrands'][5];
$companyname=$_POST['companyname'][5];
$cmpyscheme=$_POST['cmpyscheme'][5];
```